# Create a detail view under a parent route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

You surely know the heroes sample from angular 2 tutorial:

```
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html
```

When you click one of those 4 top heroes you get from the /dashboard url to the detail/id url.

That the whole dashboard component is switched with the detail component is fine!

What I would like to have changed is that the url changes from `/dashboard` to `/dashboard/detail/id`

So in my route config I just change

```
path: '/detail/:id',
```

to

```
  path: '/dashboard/detail/:id',
```

That works but when the dashboard url is changed then the `/dashboard/detail/:id` url makes no sense anymore.

I would like to configure the detail route depending to the 'parent' route.

How can I do this?

Comment: it is not clear from your question what exactly is wrong?

Comment: If I replace the route with the url '/dashboard' with '/test' then the other route 'dashboard/detail/:id' should also change to 'test/detail/:id'. That means I do not want to hardcode the url of the parent into the child url. In angularjs 1.x and the ui router the state of the parent inherited the url:    .state('dashboard', therefore .state('dashboard.detail', resolved in the url 'parentUrl/detail/3' You get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed routing to show how it can be done, see [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7LAt2fivTRPfFv4ZIqdi?p=preview).

In general it is done using non-terminal routes and child routers.

```
{
  path: '/dashboard/...',
  name: 'Dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  useAsDefault: true
}
```

Comment: Nearly perfect, just you slightly misunderstood me. Original quote:"That the whole dashboard component is switched with the detail component is fine!" I also want the the 4 heroes disappear and instead the details form is rendered. Just imagine a show_details button over the heroes grid. You click it then the details are visible and the heroes are gone...

Comment: Is it really needed that the 'dashboard.component.ts' has the same route definition with the name 'Dashboard' this seems redundant to me as the app/app.component.ts already has this definition!?

Comment: there is no duplicate definitions

Comment: The dummy class has the same code as the DashboardComponent class.  That is redundant and not needed. I just ask myself is that just a stupid heroes sample - and it could be improved - I do not know. But it gives me a wrong impression.

Comment: ok now it makes more sense to see that the DashboardComponent class is just a placeholder for the: 
<router-outlet></router-outlet> and serving as a parent wrapper for the child views like hero detail edit page or heros list page. Thanks kemsky.