# Routing redirecting to root

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to route using `Router.navigate` method. I followed the instructions to the letter, but when I route via API, its reloading the root page.

In my `RootComponent` I am trying to use

> this._router.navigate(['ABC', 'Page1']); which should redirect me to application/abc/xyz

But if I directly visit `application/abc/xyz` through my browser, it is working seamlessly

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {RootComponent} from "./components/root.component";
import {Page1Component} from "./components/page1.component";


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '',
        name: 'Root',
        component: RootComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/abc/...',
        name: 'ABC',
        component: ABCComponent
    }
])

export class AppComponent {
}
```

**ABCComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'abc',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/xyz',
        name: 'Page1',
        component: Page1Component
    }
])
export class ABCComponent{

    constructor(private _router:Router){
    }

}
```

**Page1Component**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {Router} from "angular2/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'page1',
    template: '<h1>Page1</h1>'
})

export class Page1Component{

    constructor(private _router:Router){
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

To explain it even simpler terms

```
                              Application (2 routes at root level)
                                  |                        |
           Default ("/") - Root Component              /abc/ ABC Component
                                                           |
                                                       /abc/xyz Page1 Component
```

What I am trying to do is, navigate to Page1 from Root Component.

**Solution**

After Reverse enineering from S.alem plunkr, here is the solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/F1p6aQNJ7lREHCiVnKEP?p=preview

Comment: What is the desired behavior. How do you do it when not route via the API. Is it then working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the main router (router of the `AppComponent`). You can get it with such a method:

```ts
getMainRouter(router?: Router):Router {
  if (router.parent === null) {
    return router;
  }
  return this.getMainRouter(router.parent);
}
```

So your `RootComponent` can be something like this:

```ts
// imports...

@Component({
    selector: 'root',
    template: '<h1>Root Component</h1>'
})

export class RootComponent{

    private _mainRouter: Router;

    constructor(private _router:Router){
        this._mainRouter = this.getMainRouter(this._router);
    }

    routeToSomewhere():void {
        this._mainRouter.navigate(['./ABC', 'Page1']);
    }

    private getMainRouter(router?: Router):Router {
        if (router.parent === null) {
            return router;
        }
        return this.getMainRouter(router.parent);
    }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eA7eNf7DtxYgMrHTKlEW?p=preview) to show. I forked the Hero Tutorial, but you can see the related codes if you fallow the route config of `AppComponent`. Launch the plunker on a separate window to see the browser url.

Comment: Router.parent will give me the main router. Since I have only one level... No need to write such a method at least in my case.

Comment: That is true, but I wanted to provide a more generic solution to get main router. Does it work when you call the `navigate()` method from the main router?

Comment: Could you check the plunker and compare it with your code?

Comment: THanks for the plunker...  It helped me a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. A live example usually works (thumbsup).

Comment: I tried to figure out that. But could not able to do it. So I  reverse engineered from your plunkr and finally got it working

Answer (score 1):

Actually router is following your configuration. You have configured 2 paths:

- `/` - mapped to `RootComponent`
- `/abc/xyz` - mapped to `Page1Component`
  This components are considered to be on the same level of hierarchy. So components replace each other during navigation.

You need to use child routers and non-terminal routes if you want to have nested components. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728297/create-a-detail-view-under-a-parent-route).

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have changed my program like above. But still it is routing to the root page... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/66aPn0?p=preview)

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'page1',
    template: `<h1>Page1</h1>
    <button (click)="navigateRoot()">to root</button>
    `
})
export class Page1Component{

    constructor(private _router:Router){}

    navigateRoot() {
      this._router.navigate(['/Root']);
    }
}
```

Ensure your server supports HTML5 pushState or alternatively to have `HashLocationStrategy` enabled

```ts
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/platform/common';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, // ROUTER_PROVIDERS can also be provided at the root component
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I am not using Hashlocation strategy. So this will not really help me.

Comment: This works the same with `PathLocationStrategy` as mentioned in my answer. Just ensure you have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` only once at the root or bootstrap in your application.